# character string as function argument r

Tags: r, string, function, character, dplyr

I'm working with dplyr and created code to compute new data that is plotted with ggplot.

I want to create a function with this code. It should take a name of a column of the data frame that is manipulated by dplyr. However, trying to work with columnnames does not work. Please consider the minimal example below:

`df <- data.frame(A = seq(-5, 5, 1), B = seq(0,10,1))`

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- function (x) {
         df %>%
            filter(x < 1)
}

foo(B)

Error in filter_impl(.data, dots(...), environment()) : 
  object 'B' not found
```

Is there any solution to use the name of a column as a function argument?

Comment: Could you make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? At this moment your are giving a dataframe with all (two) values above 1.

Comment: Thanks Jaap for your advice, I edited the df to ensure reproducibility

Comment: I remember a similar question which was answered by @Richard Scriven. I think you need to write something like `foo <- function(x,...)filter(x,...)` I have the following right now. Not sure if I am writing something correct. But the outcome seems to be right.`foo <- function (x,...) filter(x,...);foo(df, B < 1)`

Comment: @jazzurro, unfortunately I can't reproduce your advices. Maybe you can contribute reproducible example.

Comment: @jnshsrs I used your df and ran the code. R returns the first row. Could you run the code with your df on your machine?

Comment: @jazzurro, OK, I could run the code. I try to implement this in my function and give a feedback of the result. Thanks so far!

Comment: @jnshsrs OK, I am glad to hear that. I will leave my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a function which accepts the string "B"  as an argument (as in you question's title)

```
foo_string <- function (x) {
         eval(substitute(df %>% filter(xx < 1),list(xx=as.name(x))))
}
foo_string("B")
```

If you want to create a function which accepts captures B as an argument (as in dplyr)

```
foo_nse <- function (x) {
         # capture the argument without evaluating it
         x <- substitute(x)
         eval(substitute(df %>% filter(xx < 1),list(xx=x)))
}
foo_nse(B)
```

You can find more information in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

## Edit

`dplyr` makes things easier in version 0.3. Functions with suffixes "_" accept a string or an expression as an argument

```
 foo_string <- function (x) {
             # construct the string
             string <- paste(x,"< 1")
             # use filter_ instead of filter
             df %>% filter_(string)
    }
foo_string("B")
 foo_nse <- function (x) {
             # capture the argument without evaluating it
             x <- substitute(x)
             # construct the expression
             expression <- lazyeval::interp(quote(xx < 1), xx = x)
             # use filter_ instead of filter
             df %>% filter_(expression)
    }
foo_nse(B)
```

You can find more information in this [vignette](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/nse.Rmd)

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. This is very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a similar question which was answered by @Richard Scriven. I think you need to write something like this.

```
foo <- function(x,...)filter(x,...)
```

What @Richard Scriven mentioned was that you need to use `...` here. If you type ?dplyr, you will be able to find this: `filter(.data, ...)` I think you replace .data with x or whatever. If you want to pick up rows which have values smaller than 1 in B in your df, it will be like this.

```
foo <- function (x,...) filter(x,...)
foo(df, B < 1)
```

Comment: I must be getting old.  I have no recollection of this.  But +1, cuz it works!

Comment: @RichardScriven I can be wrong. But, I think it was you who answered a similar question using `select()`. That was my inspiration. The code above works, but I was surprised when I saw that.