# Filter data frame by character column name (in dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and want to filter it in one of two ways, by either column "this" or column "that".  I would like to be able to refer to the column name as a variable. How (in `dplyr`, if that makes a difference) do I refer to a column name by a variable?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(this = c(1, 2, 2), that = c(1, 1, 2))
df
#   this that
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    1
# 3    2    2
df %>% filter(this == 1)
#   this that
# 1    1    1
```

But say I want to use the variable `column` to hold either "this" or "that", and filter on whatever the value of `column` is. Both `as.symbol` and `get` work in other contexts, but not this:

```
column <- "this"
df %>% filter(as.symbol(column) == 1)
# [1] this that
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
df %>% filter(get(column) == 1)
# Error in get("this") : object 'this' not found
```

How can I turn the value of `column` into a column name?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Trying to parameterize the choice of variable?

Comment: I have a data set with two types of things in it, and different columns for each. I want to approach things this way because I'm using Shiny to make an interactive visualization and I want to let people choose which type of thing to look at, but then use the same code to extract the data, passing in the column name based on their choice.

Comment: Almost posted my question and found this :)

Comment: @Salim B's answer below is one of the best I've seen on this (confusing to me) topic. If you are looking to encode both the LHS and RHS of the `filter` arguments in a variable, this post has another approach: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/filtering-with-string-statements-in-dplyr/

Comment: Here is a discussion of how to use a variable on the RHS when the variable name matches a column name: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3139

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## Using rlang's [*injection*](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html) paradigm

From the [current dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/se-deprecated.html) (emphasis by me):

> dplyr used to offer twin versions of each verb suffixed with an underscore. These versions had standard evaluation (SE) semantics: rather than taking arguments by code, like NSE verbs, they took arguments by value. Their purpose was to make it possible to program with dplyr. However, **dplyr now uses tidy evaluation semantics**. NSE verbs still capture their arguments, but **you can now unquote parts of these arguments. This offers full programmability with NSE verbs.** Thus, the underscored versions are now superfluous.

So, essentially we need to perform two steps to be able to refer to the value `"this"` of the variable `column` inside `dplyr::filter()`:

1. **We need to turn the variable `column` which is of type character into type [`symbol`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html).**

   Using base R this can be achieved by the function `as.symbol()`
   which is an alias for `as.name()`. The former is [preferred by the
   tidyverse developers](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_name.html#details) because it

   > follows a more modern terminology (R types instead of S modes).

   Alternatively, the same can be achieved by [`rlang::sym()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/sym.html) from the tidyverse.
2. **We need to inject the symbol from 1) into the `dplyr::filter()` expression.**

   This is done by the so called [*injection operator* **`!!`**](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/injection-operator.html) which is basically [syntactic
   sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) allowing to modify a piece of code before R evaluates it.

   <sub>(In earlier versions of `dplyr` (or the underlying `rlang` respectively) there used to be situations (incl. yours) where `!!` would collide with the single `!`, but this is not an issue anymore [since `!!` gained the right operator precedence](https://web.archive.org/web/20211011104717/https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html#life-cycle).)</sub>

Applied to your example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(this = c(1, 2, 2),
                 that = c(1, 1, 2))
column <- "this"

df %>% filter(!!as.symbol(column) == 1)
#   this that
# 1    1    1
```

## Using alternative solutions

Other ways to refer to the value `"this"` of the variable `column` inside `dplyr::filter()` *that don't rely on rlang's injection paradigm* include:

- Via the [*tidyselection*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#tidy-selection) paradigm, i.e. [`dplyr::if_any()`/`dplyr::if_all()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) with [`tidyselect::all_of()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/all_of.html)

  ```r
  df %>% filter(if_any(.cols = all_of(column),
                       .fns = \(x) x == 1))
  ```
- Via [rlang's `.data` pronoun](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dot-data.html) and [base R's `[[`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Extract.html):

  ```r
  df %>% filter(.data[[column]] == 1)
  ```
- Via [magrittr's `.` argument placeholder](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/#the-argument-placeholder) and [base R's `[[`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Extract.html):

  ```r
  df %>% filter(.[[column]] == 1)
  ```

Comment: For the latter case you could use some extra round brackets `df %>% filter((!!as.name(column)) == 1)`

Answer (score 24):

I would steer clear of using `get()` all together.  It seems like it would be quite dangerous in this situation, especially if you're programming.  You could use either an unevaluated call or a pasted character string, but you'll need to use `filter_()` instead of `filter()`.

```
df <- data.frame(this = c(1, 2, 2), that = c(1, 1, 2))
column <- "this"
```

**Option 1** - using an unevaluated call:

You can hard-code `y` as `1`, but here I show it as `y` to illustrate how you can change the expression values easily.

```
expr <- lazyeval::interp(quote(x == y), x = as.name(column), y = 1)
## or 
## expr <- substitute(x == y, list(x = as.name(column), y = 1))
df %>% filter_(expr)
#   this that
# 1    1    1
```

**Option 2** - using `paste()` (and obviously easier):

```
df %>% filter_(paste(column, "==", 1))
#   this that
# 1    1    1
```

The main thing about these two options is that we need to use `filter_()` instead of `filter()`.  In fact, from what I've read, if you're programming with `dplyr` you should always use the `*_()` functions.

I used this post as a helpful reference: [character string as function argument r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989627/character-string-as-function-argument-r), and I'm using `dplyr` version 0.3.0.2.

Comment: Option 1 is a robust solution as recommended by @hadley in several posts on SO and in the vignette("nse"). However, it looks like it goes against hadley's style of elegant function calls. Can't it be wrapped and presented in a simpler way?

Comment: why is get() considered dangerous?

Comment: This is a good answer for older versions of `dpylr` but the underscore functions are deprecated so @Salim-B's answer below is better going forward.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another solution for the latest dplyr version:

```
df <- data.frame(this = c(1, 2, 2),
                 that = c(1, 1, 2))
column <- "this"

df %>% filter(.[[column]] == 1)

#  this that
#1    1    1
```

Answer (score 9):

Regarding Richard's solution, just want to add that if you the column is character. You can add `shQuote` to filter by character values.

For example, you can use

```
df %>% filter_(paste(column, "==", shQuote("a")))
```

If you have multiple filters, you can specify `collapse = "&"` in `paste`.

```
df %>$ filter_(paste(c("column1","column2"), "==", shQuote(c("a","b")), collapse = "&"))
```

Answer (score 6):

The latest way to do this is to use `my.data.frame %>% filter(.data[[myName]] == 1)`, where `myName` is an environmental variable that contains the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter_at(vars(column), any_vars(. == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Salim B explained above but with a minor change:

```
df %>% filter(1 == !!as.name(column))
```

i.e. just reverse the condition because `!!` otherwise behaves 
like

```
!!(as.name(column)==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the across(all_of()) syntax, it takes a string as argument

```
column = "this"
df %>% filter(across(all_of(column)) == 1)
```