# Passing a column name as a function parameter to dplyr filter function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to pass in a column name to the dplyr filter function, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I always return all of the rows.

Is there a way to make this work?  Ideally one where this could be run both with "carb" and carb.  One with and without the quotes.

```
 help=function(colname){
 filter(mtcars, colname > 2)}

 results=help(carb)
```

Comment: Could you make your example more explicit, i.e. input data and expected output.

Comment: Your function has a missing `)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr