# How to call upon this object, within R, as a string?

Tags: r, object, filter, dplyr

This question will be bountied by me eventually if no one gives a satisfactory answer.

I have the following code in R

```
library(dplyr)
Data <- iris %>% filter(Petal.Length > 5)
```

The `filter` function calls upon the iris object and subsets the data by the `Petal.Length` variable.

What I want is to be able to pass a string through the filter function such that something like this would give the ***same*** result.

```
Data <- iris %>% filter(get("Sepal.Length") > 5)
```

The above code gives an error though

> Error: object 'Sepal.Length' not found

If it's of any benefit for context, `get` works with the `select` function within `dplyr`. For example...

```
Data <- iris %>% select(Sepal.Length)

Data1 <- iris %>% select(get("Sepal.Length"))
```

give the same results.

Is there any way to make it such that the two `filter` statements, where one could pass a string through the latter one, would give the same output?

Comment: There's a whole [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) in the dplyr docs that deals with this, as well as I'm sure numerous duplicates that someone will dig up shortly here. If you look, most of those functions have alternate version like `filter_` and `select_` for precisely this purpose.

Comment: `iris %>% filter_(~Petal.Length > 5)` or `iris %>% filter_("Petal.Length > 5")`, but read the Vignette and look at SO questions on Standard vs. Non-Standard evaluation in `dplyr`.

Comment: ...[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27197858/324364) is one example.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will have to read that. This question has been nagging me for a while. I wasn't aware of the `filter_`, `~var`  functions.

Comment: Some more examples [here](http://justanotherdatablog.blogspot.com/2015/03/dplyr-use-cases-non-interactive-mode.html).

Comment: I can't quite think of any examples off the top of my head, but it seems rather coincidental that this would be available through `dplyr`. I guess for functions outside of dplyr, it would depend on the package or function themselves.

Yes, this is a duplicate as `Coatless` mentions.