# Evaluate condition using quasiquotation

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I would like to filter a dataframe `df` based on some `filter_phrase` using quasiquotation (similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219732/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrfilter?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However, instead of dynamically setting the column, I would like to evaluate the entire condition:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
filter_phrase <- "a < 4"
df %>% filter(sym(filter_phrase))
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
> df %>% filter(a < 4)
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `parse_expr`.  The 'filter_phrase' is an expression as a string.  We can convert it to `langauge` class with `parse_expr` and then evaluate with (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
     filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(filter_phrase))
#  a b
#1 1 a
#2 2 b
#3 3 c
```

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect! Problem solved :-) Do you mind elaborating a bit on what is happening in your code?

Comment: @BenNutzer  Also, if the intial obect is a language class (with `quo`) i.e. `filter_phrase <- quo(a < 4); df %>% filter(!!filter_phrase)`