# Pass a string as variable name in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been reading from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219732/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrfilter) SO post on how to work with string references to variables in dplyr.

I would like to mutate a existing column based on string input:

```
var <- 'vs'
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(get(var) = factor(get(var)))
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   "my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
>     mutate(get(var) ="

Also tried:

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!! rlang::sym(var) = factor(!! rlang::symget(var)))
```

This resulted in the exact same error message.

How can I do the following based on passing string 'vs' within var variable to mutate?

```
# works
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This operation can be carried out with `:=` while evaluating (`!!`) and using the conversion to `sym`bol and evaluating on the rhs of assignment

```
library(dplyr)
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
       mutate(!! var  := factor(!! rlang::sym(var)))
class(my_mtcars$vs)
#[1] "factor"
```

---

Or without thinking too much, use `mutate_at`, which can take strings in `vars` and apply the `function` of interest

```
my_mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
                    mutate_at(vars(var), factor)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Does one read `:=` as 'update' in the same way one can read the pipe operator as 'and then'?

Comment: @DougFir It is an assignment operator (similar to the one used in data.table, but with different behavior).  This assignment operator does evaluate on the lhs and rhs

Comment: Maybe we can also use `{{}}`, not sure how we can use it to capture `var` and use it for naming though.

Comment: @NelsonGon `mtcars %>% mutate("{x}"  := factor(!! rlang::sym(x)))` works, see `vignette("programming", "dplyr")`. But I'm not sure if/how to replace `factor(!! rlang::sym(x))`. @akrun do you know if `{{}}` can/should be used to replace the use of `!!` on the right hand side?

Comment: @JWilliman I have not tested but you can try mtcars %>%  mutate(var = factor({{var}}))