# R function create custom variable name

Tags: r, function

I have written a function to calculate the mean values from monthly data within a year (starting in the previous Dec to the current Sep). Each dataframe (and there are many) that I'm feeding through this function is presently named for the variable that I'm interested in. But I want the output to use the name of the dataframe as the variable.

Example:

```
year <- c(2000:2020)
`1` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`2` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`3` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`4` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`5` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`6` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`7` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`8` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`9` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`10` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`11` <- runif(21, 0,10)
`12` <- runif(21, 0,10)
dogs <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`))

fun_annual <- function(df) { 
  name = deparse(substitute(df)) #I know I can use this to get the name of the dataframe
  df %>% 
  mutate(lag12 = lag(`12`)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% # complete next calculations row by row
  mutate(name = mean(c_across(c(`1`:`9`, lag12)))) %>% #mean from prev Dec to Sep
  select(year, name) #by this point 'name' should be 'dogs' (name of original dataframe
}
# Final function should return a dataframe with 2 variables: year and dogs
```

**Bonus points** if someone can also help be figure out how to put the months in the function, so I don't have to change the months within the function each time!  Especially if I use more months from the previous year (beyond Dec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Pass a string as variable name in dplyr::mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690702/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrmutate), you can use `rlang`'s `!!`, `sym()`, and `:=`.

`sym` takes the value from `name` and turn it into a symbol. `!!` makes sure that `sym` takes effect before R evaluate the code. And, as there is no `sym()<-` function, we can't use `=` to modify the left hand side, and need to use the `glue` package syntax with `:=`.

Also, you can use `dplyr::all_of` to get the columns for the months.

```
fun_annual <- function(df, months) { 
  name = deparse(substitute(df))
  df %>% 
    mutate(lag12 = lag(`12`)) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(!!sym(name) := mean(c_across(c(all_of(months), lag12)))) %>%
    select(year, !!sym(name))
}

> fun_annual(dogs, paste(1:9))
# A tibble: 21 × 2
# Rowwise: 
year  dogs
<dbl> <dbl>
  1  2000 NA   
2  2001  4.33
3  2002  5.67
4  2003  3.68
5  2004  4.07
6  2005  5.52
7  2006  5.98
8  2007  6.34
9  2008  6.18
10  2009  3.66
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the syntax!  This will be super helpful when I need to write other functions.

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but slightly different:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fun_annual  <- function(df) {
  name <- quo_name(enquo(df))
  
  df |>
    mutate(lag12 = lag(`12`)) |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate("{name}" := mean(c_across(c(`1`:`9`, lag12)))) |>
    select(year, !!name)
    
}

fun_annual(dogs)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     year  dogs
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2000 NA   
#>  2  2001  5.58
#>  3  2002  5.72
#>  4  2003  3.89
#>  5  2004  4.77
#>  6  2005  3.98
#>  7  2006  5.98
#>  8  2007  4.61
#>  9  2008  5.23
#> 10  2009  5.91
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

EDIT

bonus for months:

```r
fun_annual  <- function(df, months) {
  name <- quo_name(enquo(df))
  
  df |>
    mutate(lag12 = lag(`12`)) |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate("{name}" := mean(c_across(c({{months}}, lag12)))) |>
    select(year, !!name)
}

fun_annual(dogs, months = c(`1`, `2`))
#> # A tibble: 21 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     year  dogs
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2000 NA   
#>  2  2001  4.76
#>  3  2002  4.74
#>  4  2003  5.35
#>  5  2004  8.11
#>  6  2005  2.26
#>  7  2006  1.90
#>  8  2007  5.75
#>  9  2008  8.35
#> 10  2009  4.81
#> # ... with 11 more rows

fun_annual(dogs, months = c(`1`, `4`, `5`))
#> # A tibble: 21 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     year  dogs
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2000 NA   
#>  2  2001  3.76
#>  3  2002  5.92
#>  4  2003  3.66
#>  5  2004  5.78
#>  6  2005  4.67
#>  7  2006  3.53
#>  8  2007  5.31
#>  9  2008  7.15
#> 10  2009  5.02
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! Always helpful to see different ways of doing the same thing!!