# How to pass column name as argument to function for dplyr verbs?

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know why passing argument from custom function to `group_by` doesn't work. I just pass a `colName` from dataset and when I run my own function then error comes up: *Must group by variables found in .data.
Column 'colName' is not found.* In my example below I use `quakes` dataset available in R environment:

```
foo <- function(data, colName) {
  
  result <- data %>%
   group_by(colName) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) 

  return(result)
}

foo(quakes, "stations")

# I also tried passing w/o commas but it is not working too:
# foo(quakes, stations)
```

I noticed, that when I pass column name explicitly to `group_by` then it works:

```
group_by(stations) %>%
```

However, it doesn't make sense to hardcode column name in function..

Comment: All answers in this post should work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219732/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrfilter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another way of making it work. You can use `.data[[var]]` construct for a column name which is stored as a string:

```
foo <- function(data, colName) {
  
  result <- data %>%
    group_by(.data[[colName]]) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) 
  
  return(result)
}

foo(quakes, "stations")

# A tibble: 102 x 2
   stations count
      <int> <int>
 1       10    20
 2       11    28
 3       12    25
 4       13    21
 5       14    39
 6       15    34
 7       16    35
 8       17    38
 9       18    33
10       19    29
# ... with 92 more rows
```

In case you decide not to pass the `ColName` as a string you you wrap it with a pair of curly braces inside your function to get the similar result:

```
foo <- function(data, colName) {
  
  result <- data %>%
    group_by({{ colName }}) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) 
  
  return(result)
}

foo(quakes, stations)

# A tibble: 102 x 2
   stations count
      <int> <int>
 1       10    20
 2       11    28
 3       12    25
 4       13    21
 5       14    39
 6       15    34
 7       16    35
 8       17    38
 9       18    33
10       19    29
# ... with 92 more rows
```

Comment: For some reasons your solution works best in my case. I write a modularized shiny app, don't know why `get(colName)` doesn't work but your solution does. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. `get` is a very useful function for retrieving an object's value, however, I guess if you are going to write functions using `tidyevaluation` you need to use Mr. @Peter's solution or the ones I mentioned. These are very useful and if you want to find out more you can type `vignette("programming")` in the console and read the documentations.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you simply need to wrap the variable name in `get`.

```r
foo <- function(data, colName) {
  
  result <- data %>%
   dplyr::group_by(get(colName)) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(count = n()) 

  return(result)
}
```

```
> foo(quakes, "stations")
# A tibble: 102 x 2
   `get(colName)` count
            <int> <int>
 1             10    20
 2             11    28
 3             12    25
 4             13    21
 5             14    39
 6             15    34
 7             16    35
 8             17    38
 9             18    33
10             19    29
```

Comment: I develop shiny app, don't know if it's a reason but when I use `get` then the error is shown: _Problem with mutate() input ..1. x Config file config.yml not found in current working directory or parent directories i Input ..1 is get(colName)_.  Anyways, your solution works fine outside shiny app.

Answer (score 3):

An option is also to use `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`) so that it can accept both quoted and unquoted argument

```
foo <- function(data, colName) {
       data %>%
         dplyr::group_by(!! rlang::ensym(colName)) %>%
         dplyr::summarise(count = n())
  }

foo(quakes, stations)
foo(quakes, "stations")
```

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr try:

```r
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(data, colName) {

  colName = sym(colName)
  
    result <- data %>%
    group_by(!!colName) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) 
  
  return(result)
}


foo(quakes, "stations")
#> # A tibble: 102 x 2
#>    stations count
#>       <int> <int>
#>  1       10    20
#>  2       11    28
#>  3       12    25
#>  4       13    21
#>  5       14    39
#>  6       15    34
#>  7       16    35
#>  8       17    38
#>  9       18    33
#> 10       19    29
#> # ... with 92 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>