# How to use a word (title of a variable in a df) as an input in a function? (r)

Tags: r, function, forecasting, variable-names

Say I have this as my dataframe:

```
    library(fpp3)
    df <- prices
```

And I want to create a function where I pass in the variable name and the number of steps forward I want to forecast. This is the function I have tried, which does not work. (I have used the 'select' function as I am doing cross-validation on my time series, but I do not need to include that code in this example)

```
fc.function <- function(variable, steps) {

fit <- df %>%
  select(year, variable) %>%
  model(
    MEAN(variable)
  ) 

fit %>%
  forecast(h = steps)

}
```

When I use the variable 'copper' for example and I forecast 1 step ahead I get an error.

```
fc.function("copper", 1)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'variable' not found
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

I have looked at multiple different answers on here but unless I missed or misinterpreted a solution, which I may have, then I cannot find my answer.

Comment: This question gives the same answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382081/passing-argument-from-custom-function-to-group-by-doesnt-work/67382231#67382231

Answer (score 1):

You are providing your function with the character value "copper" (and not a symbol). You can convert to a symbol with `sym` and then unquote using `!!` within the `dplyr` statements.

```
fc.function <- function(variable, steps) {
  df %>%
    select(year, !!sym(variable)) %>%
    model(MEAN(!!sym(variable))) %>%
    forecast(h = steps)
}
```