# Passing argument into function for group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use group_by within a function call in dplyr (R) and I am getting unexpected results. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(0,0,1,1), b = c(0,1,0,1), c = c(1,2,3,4))

result1 = df %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>%
  mutate(d = sum(c))
result1$d

myFunc <- function(df, var) {
  output = df %>%
    group_by(a,!!var) %>%
    mutate(d = sum(c))
  return(output)
}

result2 = myFunc(df,"b")
result2$d
```

result1$d yields [1,2,3,4] which is what I expected. result2$d yields [3,3,7,7] which I do not want, and I am not sure what is going on.

It works to have b (without quotes) as the function argument, and {{var}} in place of !!var. Unfortunately, in my case, my column names are in string format (but maybe there is a way to transform the string beforehand so that it will work with the {{}} notation?)

Comment: I believe you can use `get()`: `group_by(a, get(var))`

Comment: @VvdL yes, but you will get an additional column named `\`get(var)\`` in the output. That's not perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass column name as argument to function for dplyr verbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382081/how-to-pass-column-name-as-argument-to-function-for-dplyr-verbs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass a character object that can refer to a certain column of a data frame, you should use `!!sym(var)`:

```r
myFunc <- function(df, var) {
  output = df %>%
    group_by(a, !!sym(var)) %>%
    mutate(d = sum(c))
  return(output)
}

myFunc(df, "b")
```

If you want to pass a data-masked argument, you should use `{{ var }}` or equivalently `!!enquo(var)`:

```r
myFunc <- function(df, var) {
  output = df %>%
    group_by(a, {{ var }}) %>%
    mutate(d = sum(c))
  return(output)
}

myFunc(df, b)
```

Note that I pass `"b"` and `b` respectively into the function in the two different cases.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to use quoting and unquoting instead of curlycurly `{{}}` the we should consider this basic procedure: https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html

Creating a function around dplyr pipelines involves three steps: abstraction, quoting, and unquoting.

**1. Abstraction step:**

- Here we identify the varying steps. In our case `var` in `group_by`:

**2. Quoting step:**

- Identify all the arguments where the user is allowed to refer to data frame columns directly.
- The function can’t evaluate these arguments right away.
- Instead they should be automatically quoted. Apply `enquo()` to these arguments

**3. Unquoting step:**

- Identify where these variables are passed to other quoting functions and unquote with `!!`.
- In this case we pass `var` to `group_by()`:

```
myFunc <- function(df, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  output = df %>%
    group_by(a,!!var) %>%
    mutate(d = sum(c))
  return(output)
}

result2 = myFunc(df,b)
```

output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as I post a question, I come across something that works...

```
myFunc <- function(df, var) {
  output = df %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = c("a",var)) %>%
    mutate(d = sum(c))
  return(output)
}

result2 = myFunc(df,"b")
```