# 'Error in !`*tmp*` : invalid argument type' error when using !! operator in R

Tags: r, eval

I am trying to programmatically initialize some variables in R so that the variable name would be the evaluated content of the string.

Just this code:

```
library(dplyr)

v <- 'sum.of.ranfx'
new_v = sym(v)

!!new_v <- vector(mode = "list", length = 122)
```

fails with

```
Error in !`*tmp*` : invalid argument type
```

Google gives me no hits for this exact error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219802/2066083) is an example accepted and upvoted SO answer whose syntax example I think I am following. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's unclear to me what is `!!new_v <- vector(mode = "list", length = 122)` doing. Are you trying to do something like `as.vector(new_v, mode = "list", length = 122)`? Also, why are you calling `new_v`  "`!!new_v`"? `!` acts as a "not" logical operator, so double `!!` does pretty much nothing, logic-wise.

Comment: My question was answered and I've accepted the answer, but for clarity, I was trying to programmatically initialize variables so that the variable name would be the evaluated content of the string. Here is an example of another person trying to use the syntax I was trying to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219732/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrfilter. `!!` is not a double negation here, but a function in dplyr, or so I understand.

Comment: I edited so that my goal would be a little clearer, but again, my question was answered to my satisfaction.

Comment: "!! is not a double negation here, but a function in dplyr, or so I understand" I can't find it. Can you point to some reference to it? I believe that is what is making your question unclear.

Comment: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html

Comment: That's not dplyr. That's a "quasiquotation" syntax symbol defined in the `rlang` package. Why were you trying to unquote `new_v`? I believe the problem may lie in the fact that you were assigning a value to an unquoted version of a variable. Maybe check this reference https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#quasiquotation

Comment: For the reason I said -- to dynamically initialize variable names from a list of strings.  Maybe this isn't really necessary in R (which I am new to) the way it would be in other languages because R won't throw an error if it encounters a list of uninitialized names?  In any case I'm satisfied with the accepted answer -- that I should use R's `assign` function.  I am curious how I am deviating from the syntax in, for example, the answer I linked in my edited version of the question, but I don't need to know this to move on with my project.  Thanks for your engagement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `assign` -

```
v <- 'sum.of.ranfx'
assign(v, vector(mode = "list", length = 122))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I am going to wait to accept it to see if someone comes along and explains what I was doing wrong above, since I thought I was following the examples online, but your suggestion definitely solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For curious future readers, here is what I was doing wrong: attaching the wrong package.  I needed `library(rlang)` in addition to `library(dplyr)`, and I was confused by the fact that one piece of example code on the internet was explicitly showing dplyr being attached, and not rlang, but that's not a feature of the SO answer I linked in the question.  When rlang is attached it runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

raw !! is not accepted, so you should put ` around the !!new to make it work

```
`!!new`= vector(mode = "list", length = 122)
```

I think it's because ! is used to 'reverse' a `T` or a `F`

ex:

```
> !TRUE
[1] FALSE
> !!TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

So when you try to create a variable without specifying the ! should be used as a character, R tries to perform this reverse operation.
Was this understandable?

Comment: That gives me a variable named "!!new".  I want a variable named "sum.of.ranfx"

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't get your question. Then you should use assign as Ronak mentionned

Answer (score 0):

We may use `list2env`

```
v <- 'sum.of.ranfx'
list2env(setNames(list(vector(mode = "list", length = 122)), v), .GlobalEnv)
```

-checking the object

```
> head(sum.of.ranfx)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL
```