# Using a string with the same name as a variable in filtering in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a string with the same name as a variable in a tibble. If I want to filter using this string, I have the following working options:

```
jahr <- 2020

test <- tibble(jahr = c(2019, 2020), fte2020 = c(10, 11), fte2021 = c(12,13))

spalte <- paste0("fte", jahr)

# Using get:
test %>% 
  filter(base::get(spalte) == 11)
# Using all in one:
test %>% 
  filter(base::get(paste0("fte", .env$jahr)) == 11)
# Using .data:
test %>% 
  filter(.data[[spalte]] == 11)
```

I thought that something like

```
test %>% 
  filter( {{ spalte  }} == 11)
```

would also work. But it doesn't. Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Cheers
Renger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sym` a tidy eval tools for details look here https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/sym.html
and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219802/13046806

```r
test%>%
  filter((!!sym(spalte))==11)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>    jahr fte2020 fte2021
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1  2020      11      13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I thought that programming in tidyverse now could be done almost solely with curly braces.