# dplyr filter_ not returning data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a "d" data frame and I want to filter dynamically.I'd like to filter column "g" for observations of "C". Any idea how to get it to work?

```
d =data.frame(g = c("C","A"))
library(dplyr)
 groups= c("g")
 filter=c("C","A")
 i=1
 d %>% dplyr::filter_(paste0( groups[i],"==",filter[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sym` to convert to symbol and evaluate with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  filter(!! rlang::sym(groups) == filter[i])
#  g
#1 C
```

---

If we are passing expressions, then it is easier to use `quote` or `quo`

```
g1 <- quo(g == "C")
d %>%
  filter(!! g1)
#  g
#1 C
```

Comment: why wouldn' toption 2 here work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr. It does not seem  to work.

Comment: @user3022875  The answer you quoted is based on old syntax and most of them are now getting replaced

Comment: hmm that works in this toy example but not on my real data frame

Comment: @user3022875  If you are talking about the answer in this post, then you may need to show a better example