# filtering data.frame character column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I have a variable term which includes loan term and has only two types: "36 months" and "60 months". I want to filter my dataset df and create two different subsets for these categories.

I have tried using the commands subset, filter,which etc but it didn't work.

codes that I have tried `df1 –> df[which(df$term == "36 months"),]`, `df1 –> filter(df, term == "36 months")` `df1–>df[df$term %in% c("36 months"), ]` and other ways but always choices zero rows.

```
head(loan_data$term)
```

[1] " 36 months" " 60 months" " 36 months" " 36 months" " 60 months" " 36 months"

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: can you add a minimal reproducible example please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you really use right assignment (`->`) or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: @joran thats a typo. SORRY

Comment: @Bulat thanks to you I saw the way the data was constructed. It had space in "_36 months" before 36

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  val = c("60 months", "36 months", "60 months")
)

df[df$val == "60 months", ]
# df$val == "60 months"
# 1  1 60 months
# 3  3 60 months
df[which(df$val == "60 months"),]
# df$val == "60 months"
# 1  1 60 months
# 3  3 60 months
```

Answer (score 0):

as more robustly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr), using...

my.data.frame %>% filter(.data[[myName]] == 1)
...

```
df60 <- df %>% filter(.df[[term]] == "60 months")
df30 <- df %>% filter(.df[[term]] == "30 months")
```

..or [here](http://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Week03a.html)

```
ssP <- mutate( nino, PHASE = ifelse(PHASE == "E", "N","L"))
```

which for your df ..

```
df60 <- mutate( df, term = ifelse(term == "60 months"))
df30 <- mutate( df, term = ifelse(term == "30 months"))
```