# ShinyApp: Use a selected input to subset some levels of a categorical variable,and use that as input for plotting in the server

Tags: r, shiny, subset, reactive, uioutput

I'm trying to plot a continous variable (y) versus another one (x), and color the data points in the plot depending on a third categorical variable (z). To select these three variables I use a selectInput function, but to select the possible categories (levels(input$z)) I want to plot, I use a uiOutput function. I'm trying to subset the selected levels in a filtered dataframe (dataf) but this is not working. Some reactive expressions are working, but I rolled back the code with the subsetting because when I use ( dataf <- filter(data(), input$z %in% input$show_levels)) in the renderPlot function I don't get any data point plotted.

I have prepared a simplified version of what I need using the diamonds dataset. For example, I would need my shinyApp to plot prize vs carats, with the points colored depending on the cut, and being able to represent only the ones with a certain cut (for instance cut == c("Fair", "Good").)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

cont_vars <- c("price", "carat", "x", "y", "z", "depth", "table")
discr_vars <- c("cut", "color", "clarity")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Analysis of 'diamonds' dataset"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        # Select variable for y-axis
        selectInput(inputId = "y",
                    label = "Y-axis:",
                    choices = cont_vars,
                    selected = cont_vars[1]),

        # Select variable for x-axis
        selectInput(inputId = "x",
                    label = "X-axis:",
                    choices = cont_vars,
                    selected = cont_vars[2]),

        # Select variable for color
        selectInput(inputId = "z",
                    label = "Z-axis:",
                    choices = discr_vars,
                    selected = discr_vars[1]),

        # Select level/s to show for the z category
        uiOutput("selected_z")
      ),

      # Show the plot 
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("scatterplot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a scatterplot
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Show levels for the discrete variable selected in input$selected_z
  output$selected_z <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "show_levels",
                       label = "Select category/ies to represent:",
                       choices = choices_z(),
                       selected = choices_z())
  })

  choices_z <- reactive({
      df <- select(diamonds, input$z)
      return(levels(df[[1]]))
  })

   output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
     # generate df based on inputs selected
     data <- select(diamonds, input$x, input$y, input$z)
     #     dataf <- filter(data(), input$z %in% input$show_levels)
      ggplot(data, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                             color = input$z)) +
        geom_point(size = 4)  +
        scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
        theme_light()
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expected to select the input$show_levels categorical variables (levels) I'm interested in the checkboxGroupInput (input$showlevels), and show only the points in the seleceted categories in the scatterplot. Right now I got the checkboxGroupInput function for the levels to appear (see image below), but I'm afraid it's not connected to the server, and all the levels of input$z are being plotted.
[how the shinyApp is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIh7n.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you had it just about set when you tried to filter the data (your commented line starting with `dataf`). You need to get `filter()` to recognize that you want it to use the column represented by `input$z`, not to use the actual value `input$z` (which is `"cut"`). If you update `renderPlot` so that the data are filtered like this

```
data <- 
  select(diamonds, input$x, input$y, input$z) %>% 
  filter(!!(as.name(input$z)) %in% input$show_levels)
```

then the app should work as you expected. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171513/3229332) has more details about why/how to deal with passing shiny inputs to dplyr functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as I expected when I added the filter function with the column represented as you said.