# How do I use dplyr to filter to a pre-defined global variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, global

Let's say I have the following scenario. My dataset changes monthly to where it uses the last day of the month + "Record Created".

So to avoid changing this multiple times in the dplyr pipe function, I want to pre-defined this variable in the global environment, so in dplyr, I can call the Columnparam in my select, filter and summarize functions.

```
Columnparam <- "7/31 Record Created"
analysis <- data %>% 
     filter(Columnparam == "YES")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Because it's looking for a "Columnparam" in the dataset, which doesn't exist.

How can I get it to call the "7/31 Record Created" string I defined in the global environment?

Comment: How about reshaping your data frame such that you can have a column `Columnparam` and thus call `filter(Columnparam == "7/31 Record Created")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `data %>% filter(!!as.symbol(Columnparam) == "YES")`. See also [Filter data frame by character column name (in dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr) for more information.