# pass the column name as variable to dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, stat, summarize

I want to get the `mean` and `sd` for several columns in a `tibble`.

I tried to pass the column as variable to `summarise` as the following:

```
t<-tibble(col1=1:10,col2=3)
s="col1"
t %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Mean=mean(noquote(s),na.rm=T),
                   sd=sd(noquote(s),na.rm=T))
```

This didn't work, it is giving

```
 Mean SD
1   NA NA
```

How to pass the column name as variable to dplyr summarise?

Comment: Use `!! sym(s)` instead of `noquote`.

Comment: `.data[[s]]` works as well. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

Comment: Or alternately this: [Filter data frame by character column name (in dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27197617/8366499)

Comment: @TimTeaFan sym(s) is returning NA too same as noquoute!

Comment: @Mariya: This `dplyr::summarise(Mean=mean(!! sym(s),na.rm=T)` is returning `5.5`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan thank you it is working! what is the meaning of the !! ?