# 'lambda' not found in model fitting

Tags: r, tsibble

I m using `tsibble` package `tourism` .

trying to do transformation and fit models to it.

```
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(dplyr)

sum_tourism <- tourism %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(sum_trips=sum(Trips))
fit <- function(ts, col){
  lambda <- ts %>% 
    features(col, features=guerrero) %>% 
    pull(lambda_guerrero)
  mod <- model(ts, arima=ARIMA(box_cox(col, lambda=lambda)))
  return(mod)
}
models <- sum_tourism %>% 
  split(sum_tourism$Region) %>% 
  map(~fit(.x, .x$sum_trips))
```

it gives me error. pls help. thx

```
! object 'lambda' not found
```

Comment: lambda is not found because you don't call it. Change `pull(guerrero_lambda)` to `pull(guerrero$lambda)`.

Answer (score 1):

To have the lambda object you need some modification in your code read this answer
[Using rlang's injection paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171513/13046806).

with this modification, the lambda vector is calculated and could be returned by the function.

I have some errors with your model
please provide the r packages used in your code

```r
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(dplyr)

sum_tourism <- tourism %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(sum_trips=sum(Trips))

fit <- function(ts, col){
  lambda <- ts %>% 
    features(!!as.symbol(col), features=guerrero) %>% 
    pull(lambda_guerrero)
  return(lambda)
}
fit(sum_tourism,"sum_trips")
#>  [1]  1.999926773 -0.549847967 -0.168440573  0.666662207 -0.005751637
#>  [6]  0.398992355 -0.221036172 -0.899926773  0.033105893  0.026759753
#> [11] -0.552176875 -0.732231571  0.443440107 -0.657039779  0.677437056
#> [16]  0.788476241  0.838297770  0.147628493 -0.899926773  0.185737932
#> [21] -0.007981998  0.387056949 -0.491568669  0.443289198  0.376520326
#> [26] -0.899926773 -0.899926773 -0.872745709 -0.038044620  0.044313692
#> [31]  0.762098703  0.030736135 -0.899926773  0.455422071  1.160665179
#> [36]  0.096452846 -0.535855516  0.738756222  0.090007587  0.689406832
#> [41]  0.407197974 -0.584847430  0.049477387 -0.304122383 -0.769245111
#> [46]  0.121514057  0.803968558 -0.426019305 -0.899926773 -0.531133400
#> [51]  0.667325493  0.109044833 -0.195416339  1.096501192  0.457220688
#> [56]  1.565333102  0.166391665  1.999926773 -0.013414117 -0.221385671
#> [61]  0.218667327 -0.899926773 -0.306734388 -0.473628340  1.045258935
#> [66]  0.365400240  0.068291558  0.670362886  1.127973610  0.626529021
#> [71] -0.439209555 -0.116154482  0.493627942  0.450986664 -0.353838979
#> [76]  0.232408170
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: the package used is `library(fpp3)`

Comment: Bob, does these changes Unlock  the error ``object 'lambda' not found``  that you have, is it ok ? you have another error ? I do not see ``model`` and ``ARIMA`` functions in the ffp3 package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpp3/fpp3.pdf

Comment: Wael, `model` is in `fabletools` package while `ARIMA` is in `fable` package. Both of them are attached packages of `library(fpp3)`. Speaking of the the rlang's in jection paradigm, I can repeat your answer above, but when trying my own code, it  created another problem `! object '658.5539' not found`

Comment: I don't have much experience with forecasting try to reproduce your model for one case before implementing it in the pipe and function