# Using strings as arguments of a function

Tags: r, eval

There is plenty of questions on this topic on SO, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string) on how to evaluate expressions, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874523/passing-a-string-as-function-argument) showing some disagreement about using `eval`, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002065/2590617) showing the `eval(substitute(.))` trick. 
A good reference to learn about non-standard evaluation (NSE) is the [metaprogramming section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) of Advanced R, by Hadley Wickham. 
I note a lot of disagreement in the answers, with some signalling the problems of [using strings as something to be evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164111/2590617).

I am in this condition of using a character string as an argument for a child function.
Here is a reprex:

```
# Consider a little toy function:
little_fun <- function(z = 2, y = 1) {
     (z + 2) / y
}
little_fun()
#> [1] 4

# I can call little_fun() on lists of arguments:
z_list <- c(1,2,3)
purrr::map_dbl(.x = z_list, ~ little_fun(z = (.x)))   # This is basically a tidyverse equivalent for lapply()
#> [1] 3 4 5

# or also:
z_list <- c(1,2,3)
y_list <- c(-1, 0, 1)
purrr::map2_dbl(.x = z_list, .y = y_list, ~ little_fun(z = (.x), y = (.y)))  # again, similar to mapply()
#> [1]  -3 Inf   5

# But I also want to assign the parameters from a more general parent function:
big_fun <- function(par = "y") {

     stopifnot(par %in% c("z", "y"))

     par_list <- c(1,2,3)
     purrr::map_dbl(.x = par_list, ~ little_fun(par = (.x)))   # <--- key line <---
}
big_fun()
#> Error in little_fun(par = (.x)): unused argument (par = (.x))
```

**My problem**: I am still unable to get my code running.

**My question**: why is it bad to use characters as function arguments? Should I avoid this? and how? I would like to understand how to improve my reasoning and learn available alternatives.

Comment: see https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-eval-parse-text-vs-get-when-accessing-a-function-td815553.html and https://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/02/12204.html and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-January/123211.html

Comment: "protect yourself against future stupidity"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't disagree with chinsoon12's answer to your question of *"Should I avoid this?"*

> "protect yourself against future stupidity" – chinsoon12

Having said that, dynamically-assigned parameter names is one place where `do.call` comes in handy.

```r
big_fun <- function(par = "y") {
     stopifnot(par %in% c("z", "y"))
     par_list <- c(1,2,3)
     purrr::map_dbl(.x = par_list, ~do.call(little_fun, as.list(setNames(.x, par))))
}

big_fun()
# [1] 4.000000 2.000000 1.333333
big_fun("z")
# [1] 3 4 5
```

I personally find programming like this at times mind-warping and problematic, and at others perhaps the only way to solve some problem elegantly. Sometimes it is the most terse, robust, and efficient solution available.

And just to check, I believe `big_fun()` by itself should match this:

```r
sapply(1:3, little_fun, z=2)
# [1] 4.000000 2.000000 1.333333
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be same as `purrr::map_dbl(.x = z_list, ~ little_fun(z = (.x)))` here?

Comment: Not with a default of `par="y"`. Have you tried it with `big_fun("z")`? That matches, too.

Comment: Said differently, `big_fun()` is the same as `big_fun("y")`, which should not match the previous example that used `little_fun(z = (.x))` (emphases on the `z`).

Comment: do.call()! Thank you very much for this, also for sharing these considerations.